# Variables in SQL script

Tags: database, oracle, variables, relational-database

I am trying to create a script that accepts different values from a user and inserts them into the database.   For two of the values, HName and SubName, I want to use these to search the database for their corisponding code, and then insert the data into the db.  I got this to work in a different script when I just did it with one variable but I can not get this to work with two.  I get the following error:

```
Enter a line number:  1
Enter a description for the item:  5 lbs
Enter an amount for the item:  30.49
Enter a Head category for the item:  Grocery
old  13:        WHERE Name = '&HName';
new  13:        WHERE Name = 'Grocery';
old  22:        WHERE Name = '&SubName'
new  22:        WHERE Name = 'Meat'
old  28:                       VALUES (&ExpNum, &LineNum, '&Descr', &Amt, HCode, SCode);
new  28:                       VALUES (         1,          1, '5 lbs', 30.49, HCode, SCode);
    ACCEPT SubName PROMPT 'Enter a Sub Head category for the item:  ';
           *
ERROR at line 17:
ORA-06550: line 17, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SUBNAME" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

I tried splitting these up into two seperate DECLARE, BEGIN, END blocks but then I still get an error which Im guessing is because I can't access the first variable in the second one.  Below is my script if somebody can please give any help/advice/tips thank you.

```
ACCEPT ExpNum NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter an expense number:  ';

SELECT *
FROM EXPDET
WHERE ExpNum = &ExpNum;


ACCEPT LineNum NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter a line number:  ';
ACCEPT Descr PROMPT 'Enter a description for the item:  ';
ACCEPT Amt PROMPT 'Enter an amount for the item:  ';
ACCEPT HName PROMPT 'Enter a Head category for the item:  ';

DECLARE
    HeadCode NUMBER;
    HCode NUMBER;

    SubCode NUMBER;
    SCode NUMBER;


BEGIN
    SELECT Code
    INTO HeadCode
    FROM HEAD
    WHERE Name = '&HName';

    HCode := HeadCode;


    ACCEPT SubName PROMPT 'Enter a Sub Head category for the item:  ';

    SELECT SubCode
    INTO SubCode
    FROM SUBHEAD
    WHERE Name = '&SubName'
    AND HCode = HCode;

    SCode := SubCode;

    INSERT INTO EXPDET
    VALUES (&ExpNum, &LineNum, '&Descr', &Amt, HCode, SCode);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not write sqlplus command in plsql code

move the following code out of plsql block:

```
ACCEPT SubName PROMPT 'Enter a Sub Head category for the item:  ';
```

Comment: I figured out how to fix it.  I was thinking about it wrong but thank you.  After I run the script, it says PL/SQL procedure completed successfully, but then if i exit my db and go back in, the record I just added is deleted.  Do you know why this happens?